# How can I process the response from $http, return a promise and bind to the result in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

**I'm using AngularJS 1.2.6**

I'm making a call to a service using `$http.get()`.  I want to process the response in the service to keep the controller clean, then return only the relevant data.  I thought that I could bind directly to the promise, and when the async call finishes a property on my `$scope` object will get updated, which will automatically update my view.

In this example I'm making a call to the Encyclopedia of Life API to get a list of multimedia objects.  I'm only interested in the images (which are always returned with `mimeType: 'image/jpeg'`) so that I can feed them into an image carousel directive.

Note: I left out the long URL to reduce clutter

**Service**

```
.factory('GetEOL', ['$http', function ($http) {

    var getPhotoList = function ( eolCode ) {

        // Call API that returns multimedia objects
        var promise = $http.jsonp( 'someURL' + eolCode ).then(function (response) {
            var media = response.data.dataObjects, // array returned from api
                slides = [];

            // Grab only the images from the API response
            _.each(media, function(item) {
                if (item.mimeType === 'image/jpeg') {
                    slides.push({
                        image: item.eolMediaURL,
                        text: item.rightsHolder
                    });
                }
            });
            return slides;
        });
        return promise;
    };
    return {
        getPhotoList: getPhotoList
    };
}]);
```

**Controller:**

```
.controller('ProfileImageController', ['$scope', 'GetEOL', function ($scope, GetEOL, SpeciesCodes) {
    $scope.codes = {eol: 1019149};
    $scope.slides = [];
    $scope.interval = 5000;


    // Shouldn't this automatically update my view when the promise is fulfilled??
    $scope.slides = GetEOL.getPhotoList($scope.codes.eol);
}]);
```

**View:**

```
<div class="col-md-3 thumbnail eol-slider">
    <carousel interval="interval"> <!-- angular-ui-bootstrap directive -->
        <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
            <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
            </div>
        </slide>
    </carousel>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Shouldn't this automatically update my view when the promise is fulfilled??

No, not anymore in Angular 1.2 , it was considered too magical, so now you have to specify the continuation explicitly:

```
GetEOL.getPhotoList($scope.codes.eol).then(function(result){
        $scope.slides = result;
});
```

Quoting IgorMinar on the change:

> Previously promises found anywhere in the expression during expression
>   evaluation would evaluate to undefined while unresolved and to the
>   fulfillment value if fulfilled.
>
> This is a feature that didn't prove to be wildly useful or popular,
>   primarily because of the dichotomy between data access in templates
>   (accessed as raw values) and controller code (accessed as promises).
>
> In most code we ended up resolving promises manually in controllers
>   or automatically via routing and unifying the model access in this way.
>
> Other downsides of automatic promise unwrapping:
>
> - when building components it's often desirable to receive the raw promises
> - adds complexity and slows down expression evaluation
> - makes expression code pre-generation unattractive due to the amount of code that needs to be generated
> - makes IDE auto-completion and tool support hard
> - adds too much magic

In 1.2, you can still opt in. You just have to tell the `$parseProvider`

```
$parseProvider.unwrapPromises(true)
```

And it'll do the same thing as Angular 1.1 did.

You can also replicate this from your service directly without angular's template unwrapping:

- Return an empty array, keep a reference to it in the service
- When the promise resolves - populate that array, since arrays are passed by reference, it will also change it in the scope.
- You can also add a `.then` method to the array (assign it the same value as the promise's then) so it is thenable itself, not sure I like that idea very much though.

Here is a very simple implementation of that:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller("TestCtrl", function ($scope,MyService) {
    $scope.items = MyService();
});
app.service("MyService",function($timeout){
    return function getResource(){
        var dat = [];
        $timeout(function(){
            dat.push("Hello"); // Note, DO NOT do `dat = something` here, that will break
            dat.push("World"); // you must change _the same reference_
        },2000);
        return dat;    
    }
});
```

[(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/QwnBX/)

Alternatively, if you return a thenable - it looks something like:

```
dat.then = t.then.bind(t); // add promise methods
dat.catch = t.catch.bind(t);
dat.finally = t.catch.bind(t);
```

And then:

```
var result = MyService();
$scope.items = result;
result.then(function(){
    alert("Also hooked on promise completion!"); 
});
```

[(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/9ULBr/1/)

Comment: But I like magic!  Can the old pattern be replicated with $resource in Angular 1.2?

Comment: @Roy yes, I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: I think returning the empty array, then populating it when the promise is fulfilled is exactly what I'm looking for. Could you give an example? I tried to implement this, but all I'm getting is the empty array -- nothing is populating from the API call

Comment: I've added an example of that. For what it's worth. While I like automatic unwrapping I find the explicit `.then` perfectly acceptable in my code.

Comment: I agree about being explicit with `.then`.  All I'm really after here is the ability to keep the logic of parsing the response from the API in the service rather than in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

A)

```
$scope.slides = [];
GetEOL.getPhotoList($scope.codes.eol).then(function(result){
    $scope.slides = result;
});
```

B) Use https://github.com/mgonto/restangular